# Add a "My cart" link to the top links

Tags: magento-2.1, mini-cart

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I want to add a *My cart* link to the top links:

[image]

Clicking this link should make the Ajax cart visible. I have displayed on the page this way:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="mycart.link" after="register-link">
        <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">My Cart</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">checkout/cart</argument>
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="false">my-cart-link</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

I have only kept the *My Wish List* link inside the top links block:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="header" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />
<move element="wish-list-link" destination="panel.top.links" />
```

A **pastebin** with the full default.xml file can be seen **[HERE](https://pastebin.com/e8i2VePV)**.

1. Is there a piece of XML code that would put the **My cart** link *near* the **Wishlist**?
2. Also, how can I put a "pipe" separator between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this section in default.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="mycart.link" after="wish-list-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">My Cart</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">checkout/cart</argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="false">my-cart-link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And after this, the link with class **my-cart-link** will be added. Now use this JS:

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $('.my-cart-link').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart').click();
    });
});
```

This will do the job.

Comment: It did not work. Could be because the layout is very customized. I have added *more code* to help you make a more accurate idea of the layout. Please have another look.

Comment: Why *name="contactus.link"* here: `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="register-link">`?

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Add Shopping Cart Link to the top Link

```
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="checkout-link">
        <arguments>
     <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">View Cart &amp; Checkout</argument>
     <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">checkout/cart</argument>
 </arguments>
</block>
```